# convert input timestamp from ist to utc (UNIX)

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I am getting date as an input parameter which is IST from some source but I have to convert it into UTC format i.e., I have to substract 5 hours 30 minutes to the date which I am receiving.

```
echo "Date format DD/MM/YYYY HH:SS"
read $input
```

I can do this writing small function which will grep HH and SS from the `$input` and then add which checking conditions which is tedious task, instead I want to know is there any way to do this ?
I found date command option which works like this:

`date -d "15/05/2014 10:12 -5 hours -30 minutes"`
not working
`date -d "15/05/2014 10:12 5 hours ago 30 minutes ago"` also not working.

Comment: `date="01/01/2013 10:12"; date -d "$date 5 hours 30 minutes"` should work fine.

Comment: Ohhh its working.. dont know what was it doing before

Comment: @anubhava sorry but to convert ist to utc i have to substract 5 hour 30 minutes from the input date and that thing I dont know.

Comment: Is your input date IST OR UTC?

Comment: @anubhava ist, I have to convert to utc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting your IST date in `$date` variable you can do this to get GMT date:

```
date="15/05/2014 10:15"
```

As a 1st step convert your `dd/mm/yyyy` date to `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
date=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {print $2, $1, $3}' <<< "$date")
```

Convert to GMT:

```
( export TZ='GMT' && date -d 'TZ="Asia/Kolkata" '"$date" )
Thu May 15 04:45:00 GMT 2014
```

To get EPOCH GMT value:

```
( export TZ='GMT' && date -d 'TZ="Asia/Kolkata" '"$date" '+%s' )
1400129100
```

Comment: my date is of format `DD/MM/YYYY HH:SS` check for `date="15/05/2014 10:15"`